# Wordpress URL Rewrite is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create my own permalink and use a custom template for that rewrite rule. Here is how I wanted my url be `http://example.com/author/{author-id}`

**My Custom URL**

```
function prefix_author_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'author/([^/]*)', 'index.php?id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
} 
add_action( 'init', 'prefix_author_rewrite_rule' );
```

**My Query Vars**

```
function prefix_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'id';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'prefix_register_query_var' );
```

**Set Template**

```
function prefix_url_rewrite_templates() {

    if ( get_query_var( 'id' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
            return get_template_directory() . '/author-details.php';
        });
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'prefix_url_rewrite_templates' );
```

So if I type url like `http://example.com/author/32` it won't load the `author-details.php` instead giving me a blank page. I am referring to this link https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/custom-page-template-page-based-on-url-rewrite--wp-30564

Comment: Maybe you forgot to save your permalinks?

Comment: Blank page means error in the code enable error reporting and debug it.

Comment: In this case, do I have to create a blank page through wordpress and then set the `template` from the **Page Attribute** or by setting the template through the function will load the template?